# What does this ladder logic schematic showing a coil in parallel(?) with a contact mean?

Tags: relay, schematics, ladder

[image]

I am confused on this schematic drawing and understanding what it means when I see the T1 coil in parallel (I'm not even sure) with the PR1 contact?

Does that mean they are logic "OR"ed together or something else entirely?

Comment: Yes, T1 OR PR1,  Relay PR1 (6) closes contacts PR1 (8) to take Timer? T1 out of the circuit.

Comment: note that PR1 contacts connect to the body of T1 not to the supply lines of T1

Answer (score 1):

The PR1 contact should not truly be connected in parallel with the T1 coil:

If it were, energizing coil PR1 (e.g. by pressing the "FIRE" button) would short Line and Neutral and blow the fuse.

Most likely device TR is not a typical relay (or even a typical timer relay).  It's always connected to L and N, so always energized.

Most likely the two extra terminals on TR control it's behavior.  Maybe it is a reset or start input to initiate a timer interval?

Answer (score 1):

- Pressing FIRE energises relay PR1.
- T1 (Timer 1) is always powered. A contact of PR1 starts the timing function. Note that the contract wires do not connect with the L1 and N wires so it's not in parallel with the timer"coil".
- When the preset time has expired T1's contact closes and turns on TRC1, etc.
- Releasing the FIRE button releases PR1, resetting the timer and opening contact T1.